# Scope with rules or modify the search result xml page?

Tags: search, search-scope

Scenario:

1. Site collection accessed by external users. so search needs to be within this site collection. Site collection has a document library with 20 documents. 4 pdfs and 16 "Link to a document" items (so I added content type rules for "link to document" to be included)
2. so I created a search scope for all the document libraries with following rules
   IsDocument=1; document lib path=include; forms = exclude; contenttype=customct include
3. 5 items in return when I do a search. I am getting 4 pdf and 1 item for the doc lib

Wish there was a straight forward blog or article on this. Can someone please help me sort out this issue.

Comment: Why do you need a special search setup?

Answer (score 1):

When search is properly configured the content will be properly trimmed so that users do not see results for content that they do not have access to.

For this scenario, I'm not sure why you would need to change the search results xslt.  You could create a custom search scope, but typically I do that when I need to set rules on the results in multiple places or on multiple sites.

you mentioned internal versus external content.  In many environments you will define separate web applications for internal versus external collaboration.  This provides the additional ability to define a second search service application dedicated to your external users.  This provides some additional assurance that internal content is not accidentally exposed to external users.